# Derivation of Owner Keys

Tags: gnosis, private

Maybe it’s a silly question but I’m a silly person so here goes, it would appear as though the Owners keys from the legacy gnosis safe app was at some point derived from the mnemonic phrase. But then once I either did an update or recovered the safe, one of the keys was changed. I used the mycrypto.com app to sort through some potential private keys and all three of the old keys was there but this new mystery key that one of the old one was changed to upon safe recovery is not on that list, so then, how was this key derived and is it possible to locate it?